# combine_results() attribute error

Tags: qiskit, programming

When I tried to execute the below program, The attribute error hits me every time, which is;

**name 'combine_result' is not defined**

What is the problem here? Did I miss a module?

`cal_job = execute(cal_circuits,`
`backend = real_device,`
`shots= 1024,`
`optimization_level = 0))`
`print(cal_job.job_id())`
`job_monitor(cal_job)`
`cal_results = cal_job.result().combine_results()`

I'm not familiar with stack :)

Answer (score 1):

The `combine_results()` method is only available if you are using Job Manager. Without Job Manager you can simply do `cal_results = cal_job.result()`.

Job Manager divides your circuits into multiple jobs and collect the their results. You can then use `combine_results()` to combine results from all jobs into a single `Result` object. Here's a [tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/blob/master/docs/tutorials/1_the_ibmq_account.ipynb) on using Job Manager (search for Job Manager) if you are interested.

Comment: thank you! I am going to search it